# "unknown package name of class" when compiling java files

Tags: java, android, compilation

A error happens when I am trying to compile some java files(based on android), the detailed error message is copied here:

> error: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/hwdroid_intermediates/classes.jar: unknown package name of class file hwdroid/R$layout.class

But, I did checked the directory, "out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/hwdroid_intermediates/", and there was a class.jar. I tried open this class.jar with a 7Zip, and found out there was a class named `R$layout.class`.
So, this error makes me confused, and very appreciated for any possible answers.

Comment: Compiling using IDE or command line?

Answer (score 0):

> But, I did checked the directory, "out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/hwdroid_intermediates/", and there was a class.jar.

You need a class**es**.jar, but maybe that was just a typo of you.